# find + grep to match exact keywords in a file

Tags: find, grep

My script is not matching exact words only. Example:
`12312312Alachua21321` or `Alachuas` would match for `Alachua`.

```
KEYWORDS=("Alachua" "Gainesville" "Hawthorne")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -qF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Comment: I tried adding -x that doesn't work.

Comment: Your issue here is that you want to use `-w` (see my answer) but in future, please show us example input and desired output. Saying that "it does not work" is not very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not told us what you actually want to do. I am assuming that you want to truncate those files that **do not** contain any of your keywords (at least that's what it looks like).

If you want `grep` to match whole words only, use the `-w` flag. From `man grep`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

In addition, `grep` cannot take multiple patterns as arguments. Your command will be expanded by `bash` to

```
grep -qF Alachua Gainesville Hawthorne
```

This means "*search for Alachua in the files Gainesville and Hawthorne*". In order to pass multiple patterns to `grep` you need to either separate them with `|` (you'll need to activate extended regular expressions with`-E`) or save them into a file and pass that file to `grep` using `-f`:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

For example, in your script you could create a temporary file, save the patterns into it and then grep (there is no reason to set `IFS` here):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

KEYWORDS=("Alachua" "Gainesville" "Hawthorne")

## Create a temporary file
tmp=$(mktemp);

## Save your keywords in that file
for word in "${KEYWORDS[@]}"; do
    echo $word >> "$tmp";
done

## Now run your find command and tell grep
## to read the patterns from the temp file
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -qwFf "$tmp" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Alternatively, build your pattern by joining your strings of interest with `|` and run grep with `-E` for extended regular expressions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

patterns="Alachua|Gainesville|Hawthorne";
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -Eqw "$patterns" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Comment: @slm thanks, almost as long as one of yours :).

Comment: ouch........... 8-)